# How to turn off HTTPS after logout of page

Tags: php, http

I used this code to enable https:

```
 if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] !== 443 && (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'off')) {  header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);   exit; }
```

But I need to release https I mean to use http after logout of mypage
how can I do that? need your help...thanks alot!!

Comment: Just redirect the user to the `http://homepage` after logout?

Comment: Add a condition to the if statement, if the user is not logged in, don't redirect to the ssl site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just verify if user is logged in with `isset($_SESSION['logged'])` where `logged` is the key you used to register a user logged

```
 if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] !== 443 && (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'off') && isset($_SESSION['logged'])) {  
        header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);  
        exit; 
 }
```

and redirect the user to the http://your.homepage.domain after logout